# How to preserve hidden elements space to prevent resizing the component each time it's displayed/hidden

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using react to hide elements by using the one line if statement inside render() method as usual, the problem is that when these hidden elements shown the size of the component changes.

an indication how the app is implemented can be found in this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-morning-267l5

From the other hand, preserving a space for each hidden element will cause showing the component with a lot of extra space that is not in use and will not look good.

What is the approach in such a case?

Let's assume for now that I want to keep the extra space (if there is no other option), so I instead of using the visibility of react one line if statement I used the condition inside the className in order to control the visibility values:

```
{/*{this.state.fabricationStatus === Constants.fabricationStatus.STARTED ?*/}
                    <tr>
                        <td colSpan="2" width="100%" className={this.state.fabricationStatus === Constants.fabricationStatus.STARTED ? "visibleElement" : "hiddenElement">
```

and in css:

```
.hiddenElement {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visibleElement {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Why not just move the icons below the Fabricate button and preserve the space.

Comment: this is the design that I got from our designer... it should be displayed only when the fabricate button is pressed the process begins.

Comment: Apologies, I meant move the icons below the process bar. But in any case, this seems like a problem you should take up with your designer if anything. Quite frankly, any solution we try to come up with will likely be scratched once your designer has their "input"

Comment: @zbeedatm I didn't understand your problem. On click of the button the progress bar must be shown?

Comment: You can have a fixed height component then.

Comment: not good enough, cause the buttons, combos,... of each component will not be aligned (not at the same row)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know react yet, but with vanilla and CSS, I would superpose the 2 elements in the same grid area and use this class on the hidden element :

```
.hiddenElement {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and on clicking the visible element, toggle it *off* for the hidden element, and *on* for the visible one.
This way with the [visibility CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) the space occupied by both element would be preserved and superposed.
[Here](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/KOXjNq) i made a CodePen example to show what i mean.

Comment: I updated my post with your suggestion, but elements are always displayed!

Comment: I have zero knowledge of React so i can't help you on this end. I added JS to my pen to show it working `onclick`